# Realm's RealmChangeListener has a behaviour I don't understand

Tags: android, realm

the `RealmChangeListener` is not working as I expected, here is what I do with it :

```
public ArrayList<NotificationMessage> getNotifications(RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<NotificationMessage>> listener) {
    RealmResults<NotificationMessage> results = realm.where(NotificationMessage.class).findAll();
    results.addChangeListener(listener);
    return (ArrayList) realm.copyFromRealm(results);
}

public void addNotification(NotificationMessage notif) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealm(notif);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Basicly I'm using Realm to store gcm messages. My `GCMListenerService` calls `addNotification()` when he receives one, and I have a fragment that displays theses notifications which call `getNotifications(this)` when it's created. It implements `RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<NotificationMessage>>` :

```
@Override
public void onChange(RealmResults<NotificationMessage> element) {
    RecyclerAdapter.refreshDataSet(Realm.getDefaultInstance().copyFromRealm(element));
}
```

My problem is that most of the time `onChange()` isn't called. Sometimes it is, sometimes several times in a row, and then it's not called again (whithout doing anything but refreshing my web page that sends the message to GCM). The notifications are well stored in database, if I call `getNotifications` again I'll see them all.

I started with realm this morning so I'd apprieciate if you have suggestion on how I should organise my "Realm" code.

---

```
public static <T extends RealmObject> ArrayList<T> convertRealmToPlainObject(RealmResults<T> results) {
    ArrayList<T> returnedData = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<T> it = results.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        returnedData.add(it.next());
    }
    return returnedData;
}
```

Comment: What is convertRealmToPlainObject?

Comment: It's just a basic util : I added it

Comment: @TimCastelijns what were you thinking about ?

Comment: I think your `convertRealmToPlainObject` is not doing what you may think it's doing. I believe it's just moving objects from RealmResults to an ArrayList, but the objects are still attached to Realm. It depends on your definition of 'plain' tho

Comment: I don't want to get any realm object out of my repo package, I'll access it from specific entry point where they'll be converted to my models (that are shared with others projects). So maybe I'm doing it wrong and I should clone ?

Comment: You should look into the `realm.copyFromRealm()` method, it detaches an object from realm

Comment: that is indeed what I was loking for thx ! the problem hasn't change thought

Comment: no that is what you should do in your converttoplainobject

Comment: I do not use it anymore, I deleted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it is hard to give specific advice, but a few pointers:

- Change listeners are only triggered on Looper events. So if you have multiple writes while handling an event. It will only trigger one `onChange` call.
- Closing the Realm means that change listeners no longer will be triggered.
- Changelisteners doesn't work on plain objects.

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand well your Looper point (not a native speaker). Should to subscribe to realm from a looper thread ? I don't really care about having one or more onChange calls when several writes occurs, my problem is that sometimes, onChange won't ever be called again. 

I only call close() when I destroy the fragment that implements the "OnChange" listener, so I guess It's ok.

The conversion toward plain objects is done in the onChange so it should be ok too right ?

Comment: Also I should have said : sometimes on change is never called

Comment: @Chritian Melchior, I subscribed from a looper thread and it works like a charm. Thank you for the tip !

Comment: @RenaudFavier Please, what how did you subscribe from a looper ? I got the same problem

Comment: @Creck I simply created a Thread that call Looper.prepare() at its beggining and Looper.loop() at the end. As I don't remember it very well, I'm not sure that it's a good way of implementing it.

Comment: Thanks for response @RenaudFavier